# I want to move to the next screen by clicking on profile option in navigator drawer widget. The next screen is user profile screen only

Tags: flutter

I have made a separate **class** named `Userprofiles` which consist of user profile information only. I want to access this page/screen through my **profile** option which is on the **dashboard screen** of my application inside n`avigation drawer widget`.

While passing the class name in `Navigator.push` I'm facing an error which says named parameter is not defined. Please help me resolve the issue as I am new to **flutter**.

```
buildMenuItem(
              text: 'Profile',
              icon: Icons.people,
              onClicked: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Profilepage(getprofiles: )));}
          ),
```

**Here is the code for Userprofiles screen**

```
class Profilepage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Userprofiles getprofiles;
  Profilepage({required this.getprofiles});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('First name'),
                Text(getprofiles.firstname)
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Last name'),
                Text(getprofiles.lastname)
              ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is happening because you have define userprofile in UserProfile screen and have made it required, so you have always to pass userprofile to ProfileScreen where ever you called it

Solution:

1. provide a user profile in the Navigation
2. remove the required keyword in userProfile screen